# How can I remove the Android application label?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I made my first app today on my phone using an application named "A.I.D.E".

How can I remove my app name and label from the top of the main screen? I named my app "YT Studio", but I don’t want to show this name and label on top of my main screen. I want it to be blank. How can I do it?

I provided the `android manifest.xml` and `main.java` file for the reference.

[image: An image showing app label and text]

#### File *android manifest.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ojhastudios.ytstudio" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="YT Studio"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:resizeableActivity = "true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

#### File *main.xml*

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code:

```java
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? The second file is a `xml` file. Not a java file.

Comment: And, you want to remove it from all the activities or only that one?

Comment: i want to remove only that one

Answer (score 2):

You can just call

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

in your activity's `onCreate()` method.

---

The method given above does not work when using an [Android 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_10) activity. It works with `AppCompatActivity`.

So, this answer will do the task.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, find your activity and then you should add this line in it:

```xml
<application>
   ...
   <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
         ...
   </activity>
   ...
</application>
```

Comment: in my activity? do you mean `Main Activity.xml` right? i have to add this line in the end?

Comment: No. You have the `onCreate()` method right? Add this line after `setContentVIew()`

Comment: Any updates @cocobar?

Comment: yeah i have `super.onCreate(SavedIntenseState);` and i have `setContentView(R.layout.main);` i added your line beneath it `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: should i run the code now?

Comment: sorry but it didnt work, must be something wrong with my IDE, its not making an apk file out of it, there is an error "unknown method `getSupportActionBar().hide();`"

Comment: can you share your activity code?

Comment: yeah, but how tho? the comment section doesnt allow me to break lines, lemme try

Comment: in the question. not in comments

Comment: ```js
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
  getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited my question again, have a look

Comment: Try to extend it to `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: do i have to replace `GetSupportActionBar().hide()` with `AppCompatActivity` or `GetSupportActionBar().hide().AppCompatActivity` or `AppCompatActivity().hide()`?

Answer (score 0):

Go to *src/main/res/values* and open file *theme.xml*:

[image]

Then change your style name to NoActionBar. It removes your action bar:

[image]

Comment: this is my style.xml file
```js<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
 </style>
</resources>``` i added `NoActionBar` in the end, but nothing really happened

Comment: @cocobar why did you use `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` change it to something else it shouldn't be from `@android:style/`

Comment: it was the default value provided in the application

Answer (score 0):

Go to *res* → *values* → *themes*

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
...
...
</style>
```

Change it to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`. The magic here is the **NoActionBar** and your toolbar will be removed completely, including the app title name. But you should know this, after you change it, it’s going to be removed from your entire project, not just the single activity.

Comment: aapt: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: Go to **build.gradle** (Module level) and check if you have the following dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'`

Comment: If your working on Android studio there shouldn't be any problem if you have done the following , but if your working on other IDE it might be a different case.

Comment: no, i dont have that dependency

Comment: add it >> sync it >> go back to **themes** >> change the parent to the above style and done .

Comment: uhh, i dont understand how